# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND', Severity 15

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

When I execute this procedure

```
exec [dbo].[usp_compare_metadata] 
     @source_db = 'db05',   --where your changes are
     @target_db = 'db01',   --where you want your changes
     @Where = 't_compliance_control',   --specific tables must be:  where name like 't_product_arrears%'
     @show_diff = 0,    -- don't change this
     @Control = '-d'    -- for deploy use -d for rollback use -r
```

I'm getting an error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND', Severity 15

on line no 1

```
procedure [dbo].[usp_compare_metadata]
    (@source_db sysname,
     @target_db sysname,
     @Where varchar(max),
     @Control varchar(2), 
     @show_diff smallint = 0) 
as 
begin 
    if @Control ='-r' 
    begin
        print '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------' 
        print '--************Rollback generated using data that is in ' + @target_db + ' and missing from ' +@source_db+ ' **********'  
        print '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'  
    end
    else if @Control = '-d' 
    begin
        print '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------' 
        print '--************Deploy generated using data that is in ' + @source_db+ ' and missing from ' +@target_db+ ' ************' 
        print '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'  
    end

    print '  set nocount on  declare @cmd varchar(max)  declare @tabname sysname declare @tabnames table(tabname sysname)  IF @Where !=''   set @cmd='select name from '+@source_db+'.sys.tables where '+@Where+' AND name not in (''t_ob_web_service_parameters'', ''t_metadata_ranges'',''t_metadata_audit'',''t_batch_task_param_conn_params'',''t_system_constants'',''t_database_version'',''t_ob_web_service_parameters'',''t_premium_rates_NotUsed'') order by 1'  ELSE    set @cmd='select name from '+@source_db+'.sys.tables where (name like ''t%'' or name like ''sys_privileges'') and name not in (''t_ob_web_service_parameters'', ''t_metadata_ranges'', ''t_metadata_audit'',''t_batch_task_param_conn_params'',''t_system_constants'',''t_database_version'',''t_ob_web_service_parameters'',''t_premium_rates_NotUsed'') order by 1' insert into @tabnames(tabname) exec(@cmd)  declare c_tables cursor for    select tabname from @tabnames order by tabname  open c_tables fetch next from c_tables into @tabname  while @@FETCH_STATUS=0  BEGIN   --PRINT 'compare_metadata '+@source_db+','+@target_db+','+@tabname  if @Control ='-r'
BEGIN    exec compare_metadata @target_db,@source_db,@tabname,@show_diff    fetch next from c_tables into @tabname  END ELSE IF @Control = '-d' BEGIN   exec compare_metadata @source_db,@target_db,@tabname,@show_diff    fetch next from c_tables into @tabname END  end close c_tables  deallocate c_tables
```

Comment: It looks like you have a mistake in your stored procedure around `PRINT   '  set nocount on  declare @cmd varchar(max)  declare @tabname`.  You start a print statement but are either missing a closing `'` or are trying to print a SQL query containing unescaped `'`.

Comment: It seems you mangled your code when posting - it is unreadable now. If not corrected, your question will likely be closed.